# Create a block for a specific page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

I want to have a sidebar for certain pages, each sidebar would contain different information. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to add blocks for a specific page but for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this in /admin/structure/block

1. go to admin/structure/block
2. search for the desired block and click in 'edit'.
3. Scroll down until you see the below panel and click in 'Pages'.

Now you can show/hide blocks per page.

[image: Block visibility settings]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you !